# Apply document-wide Jquery UI theme to buttons generated from ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, themes

I have some  elements which are generated on document load, and some which are generated dynamically via ajax calls.

The first ones are styled easily using

```
$(".btn").button()
```

I'm having a hard time styling the ajaxed buttons. If there was some event that was suitable, I would simply bubble to document level on load, something like this:

```
$(document).on("something",function(){
   $(".btn").button()
})
```

I've tried using on "load" and on "ready", neither works. Any ideas?

Edit: I can of course apply .button() on each ajax callback, but there is an easier way, right? ;)

Comment: what is `button()`? a plugin?

Comment: Yes. As my title says, it's [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/):

```
$('.btn').ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $(this).button();
});
```